# How to assign a 2d libreoffice calc named range to a python variable. Can do it in Libreoffice Basic

Tags: python, python-3.x, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

I can't seem to find a simple answer to the question. I have this successfully working in Libreoffice Basic:

```
NamedRange = ThisComponent.NamedRanges.getByName("transactions_detail")

RefCells = NamedRange.getReferredCells()

Set MainRange = RefCells.getDataArray()
```

Then I iterate over MainRange and pull out the rows I am interested in.

Can I do something similar in a python macro? Can I assign a 2d named range to a python variable or do I have to iterate over the range to assign the individual cells?

I am new to python but hope to convert my iteration intensive macro function to python in hopes of making it faster.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LibreOffice can be manipulated from Python with the library `pyuno`. The documentation of `pyuno` is unfortunately incomplete but going through [this tutorial](http://christopher5106.github.io/office/2015/12/06/openoffice-libreoffice-automate-your-office-tasks-with-python-macros.html) may help.

To get started:

> Python-Uno, the library to communicate via Uno, is already in the LibreOffice Python’s path. To initialize your context, type the following lines in your python shell :

```
import socket  # only needed on win32-OOo3.0.0
import uno

# get the uno component context from the PyUNO runtime
localContext = uno.getComponentContext()

# create the UnoUrlResolver
resolver = localContext.ServiceManager.createInstanceWithContext(
                "com.sun.star.bridge.UnoUrlResolver", localContext )

# connect to the running office
ctx = resolver.resolve( "uno:socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;StarOffice.ComponentContext" )
smgr = ctx.ServiceManager

# get the central desktop object
desktop = smgr.createInstanceWithContext( "com.sun.star.frame.Desktop",ctx)

# access the current writer document
model = desktop.getCurrentComponent()
```

Then to get a named range and access the data as an array, you can use the following methods:

```
NamedRange = model.NamedRanges.getByName(“Test Name”)
MainRange = NamedRange.getDataArray()
```

However I am unsure that this will result in a noticeable preformance gain.